# SSRS: Calculating percent change within a Group in Report Builder

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Something that seems like it should be simple, is causing me quite a headache.  I have a table based off an MDX query (simple drag-and-drop from a Cube) and would like to calculate a % increase of values within a group.

[It won't let me post an image because I'm new, so please see:

[image]

In the column groups, I have "Metric" and "Year".  I'm trying to get a column to the right of each year, saying, for example, that year 2011 was X% of year 2010.  Every time I try to use a Previous() or Last() function as an expression, it doesn't work.  If someone could let me know how to handle this one without doing some crazy custom MDX query, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't: you'll need to include that calculation as a computed column in your MDX query.  I'm not a cube expert, but can you get the query that's created by your drag-and-drop operation?  If so, add it to your post and an MDX expert might be able to help you alter it to suit your needs.